# Firebase android, location

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, location

I need to set up all markers on my map from my firebase database, I do it in onMapReady method:

```
@Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;
        DatabaseReference db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

        db.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {


                for (DataSnapshot child : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    double allLat = (double) child.child("lat").getValue();
                    double allLng = (double) child.child("lng").getValue();
                mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(allLat, allLng)).title("Пользователь"));}
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this, "Не найдены пользователи", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
```

I get an error:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'double java.lang.Double.doubleValue()' on a null object reference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code expects the database to be structured as shown below, where each child location contains a `lat` and a `lng` value that is a double.  If the database does not have this structure, or one of the lat/lng properties is missing, `child.child("lat").getValue()` will return null, and an exception will be thrown.

You can eliminate the cast to double with this change:

```
double allLat = child.child("lat").getValue(Double.class);
double allLng = child.child("lng").getValue(Double.class);
```

Also, you should use `addListenerForSingleValueEvent()` instead of `addValueEventListener()`.  You only need the data once, you don't want to leave the listener attached.

```
{
  "key1" : {
    "lat" : 33.0,
    "lng" : 110.0
  },
  "key2" : {
    "lat" : 34.0,
    "lng" : 111.0
  },
  "key3" : {
    "lat" : 35.0,
    "lng" : 112.0
  },
  "key4" : {
    "lat" : 36.0
    // error: lng is missing, will be read as null, causing exception
  }
}
```